# TP sends signal to subscribers from which function in Kdb+?

Tags: kdb

I know at EOD, TP sends signal to all its subscribers and call .u.eod function. However, what function in TP that sends signals to its subscribers?  I would like to know. I am currently revising my CTP code and worried the signal will not be sent to its subscribers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in `.u.end`, see https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick/u.q#L18

```
end:{(neg union/[w[;;0]])@\:(`.u.end;x)}
```

When .u.end is triggered take the union of all subscriber handles from the `.u.w` dictionary and to each one send a `.u.end` call with `x` being the date that has just finished

Comment: Worth noting that this is sent async, so any kind of expensive EOD process on a remote process will not block the TP from serving other clients.

Comment: but what function triggers .u.end at 00:00?

Comment: There are two main things that cause activity in a tickerplant.....incoming data (aka a call to `.u.upd`) or a timer (`.z.ts`). If you look at both you'll see a check which can trigger end of day (`.u.ts` or just `ts` when written in scope of the .u namespace)